# How can i use regex in Amazon EC2 filters in tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, search, amazon-ec2, ansible, filtering

This is working fine for me in ansible

```
- ec2_remote_facts:
     region: "{{region}}"
     filters:
        "tag:Name": "server1"
```

But i want to have regex like

```
 - ec2_remote_facts:
     region: "{{region}}"
     filters:
        "tag:Name": "server1*"
```

How can i do that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. You can specify `*` in `tag:Name` filter.

```
  - ec2_remote_facts:
      region: us-east-1
      filters:
        "tag:Name": server1*
    register: myinsts

  - debug: msg="Total instances that match the tag-Name pattern {{myinsts.instances | length}}"
```

Output:

```
"msg": "Total instances that match the tag-Name pattern 29"
```

Comment: Nitpick: that's not a regex. It acts more like a shell glob ("server1*" does not mean "server" followed by zero or more 1s, it means "server1" optionally followed by some characters). '?' is a wildcard for a single character.

Comment: How can I use this regex in the ec2 console website to filter out instances ?